# Getting the value of label of the polygon clicked

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using Google Earth Engine to display a shapefile. I have also added an inspector to get lat/long. in my shape file i have the attribute table with the name "DIVISION_N", when i click on the shape file, i want to know which polygon is clicked, then find the attribute("DIVISION_N") of this polygon and display on the UI

```
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text')

var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(p)

Map.addLayer(shp, {},'Divison Layer');
Map.setCenter(74.7973,34.0837, 7)

// // Create an empty image into which to paint the features, cast to byte.
// var empty = ee.Image().byte();
// // Paint all the polygon edges with the same number and width, display.
// var outline = empty.paint({
//   featureCollection: shp,
//   color: 'AREA',
//   width: 3
// });
// Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'edges');



var Scale = Map.getScale()*1
var labels = shp.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat)
  var name = ee.String (feat.get("DIVISION_N"))
  var centroid = feat.geometry().centroid()
  var t = text.draw(name, centroid,Scale,{
    fontSize: 10,
    textColor:'Red',
     OutlineWidth:0.5,
     OutlineColor:'white'
    
  })
  return t
  })
  var Labels_Final = ee.ImageCollection(labels)
  Map.addLayer(Labels_Final,{},"Division Labels")
  
  
  
//   // Create an empty image into which to paint the features, cast to byte.
// var empty = ee.Image().byte();

// // Paint all the polygon edges with the same number and width, display.
// var outline = empty.paint({
//   featureCollection: shp,
//   color: 1,
//   width: 3
// });
// Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'Division Edges');



Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');

// Create a panel and add it to the map.
 var inspector = ui.Panel([ui.Label('Click to get info')]);
Map.add(inspector);




Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  // Show the loading label.
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({
    value: 'Loading...',
    style: {color: 'gray'}
  }));

  var click_point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
  var list = shp.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['DIVISION_N']  ).get('list');
 
    
    console.log(list);
   inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({value: 'Long: ' + coords.lon + ' Lat:'+ coords.lat}))
  // inspector.clear()
   


});
```

heres the link

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f22fd8c771c05e86968236a435e03b4?accept_repo=users%2Ftylere%2Fg4g18-ee101

Comment: For this behavior, you need to include a function for retrieving the index of feature based in its intersection with clicked point. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this behavior, you need to include a function for retrieving the index of feature based in its intersection with clicked point. Following code snippet illustrates expected behavior.

```
Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  // Show the loading label.
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({
    value: 'Loading...',
    style: {color: 'gray'}
  }));

  var click_point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);

  var list = shp.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['DIVISION_N']).get('list');

  var shp_lst = shp.toList(shp.size());
  
  var retIdx = shp_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
    var idx = shp_lst.indexOf(ele);
  
    return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Feature(ele).intersects(click_point), idx, 0);
  
  }).removeAll([0]);

  retIdx = retIdx.get(0).getInfo();
  
  var name = ee.List(list).get(retIdx);

  console.log(list);
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({value: 'Long: ' 
                                       + coords.lon 
                                       + ' Lat:'+ coords.lat + ' '
                                       + name.getInfo()
  }));
  //inspector.clear();
   
});
```

Complete code can be obtained [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bbaccd6babe8a4cad06c967525ec7703?accept_repo=users%2Ftylere%2Fg4g18-ee101).

After running it in GEE code editor, I got result of following picture after clicking in some point (specifically 74.9291359375, 32.70713830426932) of feature represented by DIVISION_N Jammu.

[image]

It worked as expected after several clicks in several areas of complete vector layer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to share your assets if you want your example to work. But probably something like this could work:

```
 inspector.widgets().set(0, 
   ui.Label({value: 'Long: ' + coords.lon + ' Lat:'+ coords.lat + 'divsion: ' + lst}))
```

Comment: i have shared it already, and this doesnt work i neeed the name of the division at that point not the whole list.. it shows this

Comment: ee.ComputedObject({ "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "dictionary": { "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "collection": { "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "tableId": "projects/jkdeers/assets/Forest_Divisions" }, "functionName": "Collection.loadTable" }, "reducer": { "type": "Invocation", "arguments": {}, "functionName": "Reducer.toList" }, "selectors": [ "DIVISION_N" ] }, "functionName": "Collection.reduceColumns" }, "key": "list" }, "functionName": "Dictionary.get" })