# Getting the value of the polygon in the selected layer, in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using Google Earth Engine to display a shapefile. I have also added an inspector to get lat/long. However I want to get the value of the column based on the polygon clicked inside this shapefile.

```js
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text')

var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(p)

Map.addLayer(shp, {},'Divison Layer');
Map.setCenter(74.7973,34.0837, 7)

// // Create an empty image into which to paint the features, cast to byte.
// var empty = ee.Image().byte();
// // Paint all the polygon edges with the same number and width, display.
// var outline = empty.paint({
//   featureCollection: shp,
//   color: 'AREA',
//   width: 3
// });
// Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'edges');



var Scale = Map.getScale()*1
var labels = shp.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat)
  var name = ee.String (feat.get("DIVISION_N"))
  var centroid = feat.geometry().centroid()
  var t = text.draw(name, centroid,Scale,{
    fontSize: 10,
    textColor:'Red',
     OutlineWidth:0.5,
     OutlineColor:'white'
    
  })
  return t
  })
  var Labels_Final = ee.ImageCollection(labels)
  Map.addLayer(Labels_Final,{},"Division Labels")
  
  
  
//   // Create an empty image into which to paint the features, cast to byte.
// var empty = ee.Image().byte();

// // Paint all the polygon edges with the same number and width, display.
// var outline = empty.paint({
//   featureCollection: shp,
//   color: 1,
//   width: 3
// });
// Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'Division Edges');



Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');

// Create a panel and add it to the map.
 var inspector = ui.Panel([ui.Label('Click to get info')]);
Map.add(inspector);




Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  // Show the loading label.
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({
    value: 'Loading...',
    style: {color: 'gray'}
  }));

  var click_point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
  var list = shp.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['DIVISION_N']  ).get('list');
 
    
    console.log(list);
   inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({value: 'Long: ' + coords.lon + ' Lat:'+ coords.lat}))
  // inspector.clear()
   


});
```

Complete code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f22fd8c771c05e86968236a435e03b4?accept_repo=users%2Ftylere%2Fg4g18-ee101

Comment: Please don't repost questions that have been closed. [Getting the value of label of the polygon clicked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422793/getting-the-value-of-label-of-the-polygon-clicked)  Instead correct the original post. Even having a helpful editor include the code isn't enough, since there is no problem statement -- You state what you want, but not what you're getting instead.

Comment: You have a tag for the Python API but your code is for the JavaScript API. Please align them when you edit the duplicate.

Comment: That question was closed , it wasn't accepting answers. I have requested a question to the community and am anticipating that someone will answer, as it's very important for me. I don't know why my question got closed . I have deleted it and here I reposted the question. Please understand I am not spamming or anything.

Comment: Please reopen this question.

Comment: You need to edit your original question.  If we allowed users to delete questions instead of improving them then lots of effort by potential answerers, who are all volunteers, would be wasted.

Comment: thank you i have done that, kindly reopen the origional question...